# Querying First Subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have a structure like the following:

```
thread {
  messages [
    {
      sender_id: AB12CD34,
      ...stuff...
    },
    {
      sender_id: EF56GH78,
      ...stuff...
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to query for threads where the FIRST message's sender_id is part of a collection of ids. Something like...

```
def threads_started_by_users user_ids
  any_in('messages:first.sender_id', user_ids)
end
```

What would the proper syntax for such a thing look like? Is such a query possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't speak mongoid, but here's how you would do this in the shell:

```js
db.coll.find({'thread.messages.0.sender_id': {$in: user_ids}})
```

The `0` in the key name identifies the first element of the `messages` array.

Comment: Cool. Ends up being `any_in('messages.0.sender_id' => user_ids)`